# Splashscreen no funciona Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

instale el siguiente plugin para poner un splashscreen y no funciona, esta es la configuración. 
Estoy generando la **app-debug.apk** y es la que estoy instalando, y cuando la pruebo en mi celular, no aparece.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Este es mi archivo .xml

```
     <platform name="android">
        <splash src="res/android/screen/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>

        <splash src="res/android/screen/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    </platform>

    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="DarkRed"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer faltan cosas, si pudieras poner todo tu config.xml estaría genial

Sin embargo a continuación te dejo un ejemplo

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.example.app" version="0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
          ...
          <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
          <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
          <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
          <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
          <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
          <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
          ...
          <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    </widget>
```

estos son los valores mínimos que deberian estar asegurate de que todos se encuentran

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó, pero le tuve que quitar lo de <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />, ya que al momento de abrir la app, me daba error y s e cerraba.